# nginx and blazor - upstream prematurely closed connection - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, blazor-server-side

I am trying to deploy a blazor server template app on Nginx, but i'm stucked with this problem.
I tried everything that I could find online, but still the same error.

error.log
*36 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:7155/"

in case of that helps, browsers just show 502 code

this is my nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##
        gzip on;


        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and here the server block at /sites-enabled/

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://dotnet;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;  # you need to set this in order to use params below.
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10080s;
        proxy_send_timeout 10080;
        proxy_read_timeout 10080;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;
        proxy_buffers 16 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

}

upstream dotnet {
    zone dotnet 64k;
    server 127.0.0.1:7155;
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem. The server block was redirecting to SSL, but when I called the upstream I was not doing it with HTTPS!

To solve the problem I just changed

```
proxy_pass http://dotnet;
```

to

```
proxy_pass https://dotnet;
```

and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/04/17/hosting-an-asp-net-core-2-application-on-a-raspberry-pi/) I made some notes on how to deploy on Nginx a Blazor Server App. I share and hope that helps.

Install nginx and start it:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo service nginx start
```

Now you need to configure it so that requests arriving to port 80 are passed to your app on port 5000. To do that, open the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file in your favorite editor. The default configuration defines only one server, listening on port 80. Under this server, look for the section starting with location /: this is the configuration for the root path on this server. Replace it with the following configuration:

```
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
```

This should prevent connection reverting to long-polling.
Reload nginx:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

The `default` under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
```

Miscrosoft [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-6.0) on how to deploy.